# Laravel websockets with pusherjs trigger event

Tags: laravel, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

I have laravel-websocket package, I want to send to backend data using sockets

.... init pusher
....
send data to websockets

```
let channel = this.pusher.subscribe('public-channel');
                    channel.trigger('client-send-message', {
                        // Event data
                        message: this.message,
                        time: new Date().toISOString()
                    });
```

How can I catch this event using Laravel?
Requirements is not use requests, only channel.trigger, Just catch data and save to database.
Does it possible?